# ArcObjects queries using selection set

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, vba

I'm new to ArcObjects and I'm finding it difficult to work with the ArcObjects 'Feature classes'. Coming to my problem, I have a Map with few layers. I have coded for the layer names to display in the first Combo-box and the Column names of the Layer selected from the first Combo-box will be displayed in the second Combo-box. The values of the Columns will be displayed in the third Combo-box(So far, So good). But now I'm working on a query that displays the values lesser than the value selected in my third Combo-box. I have been using VB.Net coding for this purpose. The query code runs something like this.

```
Dim hook = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex(Table number)
    Dim FClass = ComboBox1.Text(Table Name)
    Dim Field = ComboBox2.Text(Column Name of the table selected)
    Dim Value = ComboBox4.Text(values in the Column selected)
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument = TryCast(m_application.Document, IMxDocument)
    Dim pMap As IMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
    Dim pLayer As IFeatureLayer
    pLayer = pMap.Layer(hook)
    Dim pFeatureClass As IFeatureClass = pLayer.FeatureClass
    Dim pTable As ITable = pFeatureClass


    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = "D:\Harsha\ArcMap_CustomTools\EGISDATA\"
    Dim pWSFact As IWorkspaceFactory
    pWSFact = New ShapefileWorkspaceFactory
    Dim pFeatureWorkspace As IFeatureWorkspace
    pFeatureWorkspace = pWSFact.OpenFromFile(FilePath, hook)
    pLayer.Name = FClass
    pTable = pLayer
    Dim pQFilter As IQueryFilter
    pQFilter = New QueryFilter
    pQFilter.SubFields = Field
    pQFilter.WhereClause = "'" + Field + "' < '" + Value + "'"
    Dim pSelSet As ISelectionSet
    pSelSet = pTable.Select(pQFilter, esriSelectionType.esriSelectionTypeHybrid, esriSelectionOption.esriSelectionOptionNormal, pFeatureWorkspace)
    pMxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh()
    Dim pFeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor
    pSelSet.Search(pQFilter, False, pFeatureCursor)
    Dim iRecCount As Integer
    s = vbNullString
    Dim pFeature As IFeature
    pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
    While Not pFeature Is Nothing
        iRecCount = iRecCount + 1
        s = s & vbCrLf & pFeature.Value(Value)
        MsgBox(s)
        pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
    End While
```

The problem is `pFeature` is always `Nothing` and it does not enter the `while loop`

Comment: try to edit the whereclause, maybe pQFilter.WhereClause = "[" + Field + "] < '" + Value + "'" Maybe you also have to delete the ' around value...

Comment: @schmiddor The same problem exist after I made the changes. `pFeature` value is `Nothing`

Comment: Did you verify the where clause for example in ArcMap?

Comment: OK I now took a different approach with the `iFeatureSelection` . Also I implemented @schmiddor 's solution and have got the results. Yes @schmiddor I verified it and you were right. I had overlooked it. your solution was a life saver.